# I'm late in identifying my interest within the major I'm taking. Are there any tips for me?

Tags: major

So I'm an undergraduate student in mechanical-aerospace engineering. I'm taking this major because after joined a competition that involves space and astronomy, I wanted to know more about space, but not through astronomy major. Then I felt like, I could learn it through learning space-shuttles. At that time, I didn't think thoroughly about my decision. All I want is I want to jump into the world of space learning not through astronomy major, but through astronautical (which is included in my mechanical-aerospace lecture).

After a long time, I remembered that I don't actually like machines. I always have a problem with operating and setting things up.
I like operating with Excel and Word. I also have an interest in programming, but as I was heavily influenced by my old thought, I think programming should be my side-job or just as a hobby. But now, I think learning space (and space shuttles) should be just a hobby. As for assembling electrical things, I don't quite like assembling PC. I just like to use it.
I also realized that for science, I like to observe and investigate more than creating or assembling something. I feel like office work is better for me than working in a workshop.

So, as I can't just let go of my major, is there data analysis-related jobs in engineering, especially aerospace? Is taking courses outside my major worth it? For my situation now, I'm still at my first year and still haven't got any advance engineering lectures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Freshman year isn't late to discover that you are not on quite the path you thought you wanted. It's a little early to worry about the kinds of jobs available for people with the degree you think you have to get.

Talk to an advisor at the school. There may be another related major that you can switch to. If not, do augment your major with more theoretical courses: data analysis and programming, and more science: physics and mathematics so you can make sense of the data you are interested in.